# Is there an option in hibernate like to populate values for already created records while creating a column?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to create a column in the database and set default value as a 1 bit(0/1).But when hibernate is run the column is created and null is populated for already created records. Is there any specific annotation or a method in hibernate to populate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with below code

```
@Column(name="columnName", columnDefinition="default '<defaultValue>'")
private String columnName;}
```

Comment: That worked as a treat. Thanks.                                                   @Column(name="flag", columnDefinition="boolean default true")